# Handling useEffect with firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, use-effect

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const userRef = firestore.collection('Users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
  userRef.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
    setUser(doc.data())
  })
},[user])
```

Here is my code and I want this to be always on subscription so that I can get the user's data changes in a live situation.
But it gave me error Warning: An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.

Any helps can I get?

```
<View>
{
    user?.likes &&
    user?.likes.map(id => <Post id={id}/>) // returns 1,2,3
    //collectedProductId.map(id => <Text>{id}</Text>)
    //user?.likes &&
    //user?.likes.map(id => <Text>{id{</Text>)  => works well returns 1,2,4
  }
</View>
```

Comment: try this useEffect(()=>{
    const userRef = firestore.collection('Users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
    userRef.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
      setUser(doc.data())
    });  
       return () => {
            userRef();
        }
  },[user])

Comment: userRef(); is not a function

Comment: return () => { userRef.unsubscribe()  }

Comment: userRef.unsubscribe is undefined so not a function

Comment: try this useEffect(()=>{ const userRef = firestore.collection('Users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid) userRef.onSnapshot(function(doc) { setUser(doc.data()) }); return () => { } },[user])

Comment: doesn't work neither

Comment: ho ok, discard that warning, use effect had a method called cleanup which is equal to a component will unmount. a warning will definitely come since you are not unsubscribing  the firebase call,  try this too return () => userRef

Comment: Its ok just getting the user.likes(What I really want to handle) It works well getting the data but if I unlike the post I liked before (1,2,3,4 was original likes, unlike3) the result shows 123 not 124, but if I refresh my app, It returns 124. What should I do?

Comment: your useEffect will work only if there is any change in user state, it will fetch current user from firebase and set the state user. so what is the value in firebase db will set in user state. you need to update the user data in firebase and then fetch the data from it. just my understanding

Comment: then how can I fetch the data from changed user with useEffect?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = firestore()
      .collection('Users')
      .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
      .onSnapshot(doc => {
        setUser(doc.data());
      });
    return () => subscriber();
  }, [user]);

Comment: If I use your code, when I console.log(user) 
it returns infinite console.logs. Is it right?

Comment: sorry my mistake , useEffect(() => { const subscriber = firestore() .collection('Users') .doc(auth.currentUser.uid) .onSnapshot(doc => { setUser(doc.data()); }); return () => subscriber(); }, []); remove user from [] , since snapshot will monitor change in user, also cleanup will unsubscribe snapshot